# Rails 4: Nested attributes readonly error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nested, associations

I have quite a complicated setup of associations to allow my model :thing to be rated, which I think can be best understood by looking at my models. Basically, when a new :thing is created, new :thing_ratings are also created based on the :ratings that belong to the :categories that the :thing belongs to.

For example, if a :category “Books” has a :rating “Plot”, then a new :thing that is created with an association to Books should have a :thing_rating also named “Plot”.

The problem is, though the :thing and :thing_ratings are created without problems, on the :thing show page, I'm getting this error:

```
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughNestedAssociationsAreReadonly in ThingsController#show 
Cannot modify association 'Thing#thing_ratings' because it goes through more than one other association.
```

How can I get around this problem? I saw an answer to a similar problem that suggested to make the association between :thing and :thing_rating readonly, but I also want to be able to create instances of another model :up_votes for :thing_ratings, and I don't think I can do that if the association is readonly.

models/thing.rb

```
has_many :category_things
has_many :categories, :through => :category_things
has_many :category_ratings, through: :categories
has_many :ratings, :through => :categories
has_many :thing_ratings, through: :ratings
```

models/category.rb

```
has_many :category_ratings
has_many :ratings, :through => :category_ratings
has_many :category_things
has_many :things, :through => :category_things
```

models/rating.rb

```
has_many :category_ratings
has_many :categories, :through => :category_ratings
has_many :thing_ratings
has_many :things, :through => :thing_ratings
```

models/category_thing.rb

```
belongs_to :category
belongs_to :thing
```

models/category_rating.rb

```
belongs_to :category
belongs_to :rating
```

models/thing_rating.rb

```
belongs_to :rating
belongs_to :thing
has_many :up_votes, as: :voteable
```

controllers/things_controller.rb

```
def show
  @thing = Thing.find(params[:id])
  @thing.categories.build
  @category_thing = CategoryThing.all
  @category_rating = CategoryRating.all
  @thing_ratings = @thing.category_ratings
  @thingcats = @thing.categories
  @thing.thing_ratings.build
  # ...
end


def create
  @thing = Thing.new(thing_params)
  @category = Category.all
  @thing.categories.build
  @thing_ratings = @thing.category_ratings
  @thingcats = @thing.categories
  @thingrats = @thing.ratings
  if @thing.save
    params["categories"].strip.split(',').map(&:strip).each do |name|
      CategoryThing.create!(category_id: Category.where(name: name).first.id, thing_id: @thing.id)
    end
    @thingrats.each do |r|
      ThingRating.create!(rating_id: r.id, thing_id: @thing.id, name: r.name)
    end
    redirect_to new_thing_path
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it turns out that I didn't actually have to associate thing_ratings with ratings at all. I just made thing_ratings belong directly to things.